# How to let ArcGIS Server see related records in a geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-rest-api, relationship-class

I have an ArcSDE geodatabase which contains multiple relationship classes.

If I add this layer to ArcMap, the relationship is automatically applied (eg, the Identify dialog allows me to drill-down to the related features).

However, if I publish this map document to ArcGIS Server, the REST endpoints for the layer don't show the relationship classes.

Similarly, if I create a new ArcMap document and create a Relate within ArcMap (using > Joins and Relates in the TOC) this also fails to appear in ArcGIS Server's REST directory.

This [sample REST directory](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSPetro/MapServer/0) does show the related data. How has this been set up?

Comment: Hi Stephen, This is not related to your question. But let me ask if you can help me with it. I am using arcgis pro. And have a SDE connection. Now I want to create relationship between couple of tables in there. However creating relashionship in there always fail saying "Query doesn't have spatial column. DBMS table not found". If you can hint me how to create relationships in SDE database would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time I have had problems with relationship classes that exist in SDE not being automatically published in a map service was because there is a problem with permissions on the account I was publishing with to see the related table in SDE.

How are you adding related feature classes/ tables to the .mxd? Is it the same user/version as the key feature class and if so is the sde connection file in a location that the SOC and Som accounts have access to?

Note that the related table must be *added to the map*, as well as being defined in the relationship class..

Comment: I think you may be right that it's a permissions issue on the relationship class. I made a replica using a file geodatabase, and the relationship class is seen automatically. Thanks for the tip

Comment: on further testing it appears that the related table must be added to the map, as well as being defined in the relationship class...

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a related problem. I'm able to see the relationship in the map service, but not in the accompanying feature service. I should be able to apply edits to the table directly in the feature service, but will have to hard code the relationships into my application. I wish this wasn't so inconsistent. (v10.0 sde, server v10.05)